# Why do shortcuts to Google Drive keep vanishing from the Finder sidebar and how to make them persistent?

Tags: macos, google-drive

I have a folder in Google Drive that I frequently need to access, so I have added it to the Favorites section in the Finder sidebar.

[image]

However, it vanishes after some time, presumably when Google Drive is disconnected temporarily (not sure though).

I have the latest Google Drive app (66.0.3.0) installed on macOS Ventura (13.0).

How can I ensure it’s not vanishing, even if the target is temporarily unavailable?

Comment: Try making an alias & adding that to the sidebar. Disconnected drives will always vanish, aliases don't. [idk if you can alias Google Drive, so not an answer as yet.]

Comment: @Tetsujin Aliases cannot be added to the sidebar. However, I found out that symlinks can. So I’ve created a folder (`~/Google Drive Shortcuts`) and added a symlink there with `ln -s /Volumes/GoogleDrive/Notes\ Inbox .` This looks good so far. The sidebar item remains intact even if I quit Google Drive (which removes `/Volumes/GoogleDrive`). So as long as the path `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` doesn’t change over time, this is probably a good solution. I’ll monitor this over the next few days and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm still on Mojave, where adding aliases to the sidebar is possible.

Comment: I had another look: What I wrote above is not entirely true. If I create an alias to a folder which is in my home directory, I *can* actually add it to the sidebar. However, the alias pointing to `/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive` can not be added. So maybe there is an exception for network drives.

Comment: I can't test this for Google Drive, but for network drives in the past I've just aliased the representation shown on the desktop. I have to admit I've never fully analysed the behaviour, it "just worked" for me.

Comment: I tried @aaronk6 's solution, turned my internet off, and restarted my machine and the links are still there. However, I am on macOS Sonoma and have found that the drives are in a different folder: `~/Library/CloudStorage/`.

Comment: @deeeeekun Recent versions of Google Drive use Apple’s File Provider API, so as you pointed out, the cloud files are now stored in a path in your home directory and not mounted as (virtual) network drives anymore. Therefore they can be added to the sidebar just like any other file, making my original question obsolete. :)

Comment: Actually, I came here because my shortcuts were disappearing and this solved it, so it's not completely obsolete.